# Why Mobile push Attribute class is @RestrictTo({Scope.LIBRARY})

Tags: mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I'm trying to set a custom attribute into the marketing cloud mobile push SDK. The attribute class is abstract class but has a method that returns Attribute.

```
@RestrictTo({Scope.LIBRARY})
public static Attribute a(String var0, String var1) {
    return new b(var0, var1);
}
```

My question is why this is Restricted and obfuscated? As there is a public method to set Attribute

```
`@NonNull
 RegistrationManager.Editor setAttribute(@NonNull Attribute var1);`
```

I would assume its intended to set an attribute by providing the parameter of type `Attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

It was originally a mistake for the create method in the Attribute class to be obfuscated/restricted.  When we decided to address this we also decided that we would deprecate this class, and eventually remove it from the SDK.  The deprecation should be reflected in an upcoming release.

Even with a current version of the SDK you would be able to modify the value of an Attribute in the registration.  The `RegistrationManager.Editor` class has a `setAttribute` method which takes in as its parameter a String for the key and a String for the value.
`@NonNull RegistrationManager.Editor setAttribute(@NonNull String key, String value)`

Comment: So basically this method shouldn't be used at all? Instead setAttribute(String, String) should be used? 
Also I noticed with setAttribute(Attribute), if I provide the same key again, its add a new attribute and doesn't update the existing attribute with same key.

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: This issue I saw on 5.1.3. Now I'm using the 5.4.2 with find and replace attribute logic.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue of the same Attribute key value ending up in the Attributes list, but on if I set that key twice with the same Editor instance.  Is that also what you're seeing?

Comment: I'm calling setting up the attribute like this

MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(new MarketingCloudSdk.WhenReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void ready(MarketingCloudSdk marketingCloudSdk) {
                RegistrationManager registrationManager = marketingCloudSdk.getRegistrationManager();
                registrationManager
                        .edit()
                        .setContactKey(contactKey)
                        .setAttributes(Attribute.a(ARG_USER, getUserName())
                        .commit();
            }
        });

Comment: I called this on every app cold start or when user gets changed.

Comment: I'm still unable to get a duplicate Attribute set in the registration.  Can you reach out to a Salesforce support representative so we could get more detail on the issues your having through that channel?

Once we release the SDK that deprecates the Attribute class then any duplicate attribute issues you're having should get resolved, but if we can I'd like to get you fixed before then.